# 4-bytes pointer in 64bit platform?

Tags: c, linux, 32bit-64bit

It's C/Linux env.

I'm thinking whether it's possible. I have an app which need to talk to each other between 32bit and 64bit platform. In its heartbeat, there is a structure like:

```
typedef struct{

          ..... //usual data type
          unit32_t* old;
          unit32_t* new;

}heartbeat;
```

The two pointers take 8 bytes in 32, but take 16 bytes in 64. It makes the size of the heartbeat different and also the possible misinterpreting of the pointers. The only code I can modify is the ones in 64bit platform. Is there any way to go around the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What do the pointers *mean*? Why not just exchange `int32_t`s?

Comment: This makes no sense. If you have to perform IPC between a 32 and a 64 bit application they'll be in different address spaces, so those pointers (however big they are) will be meaningless anyway. The same holds for any other kind of serialization.

Comment: Who is upvoting this? What insights can possibly be gained from this question?

Comment: En, make sense. Let me do more check.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You could request that `mmap` put the shared memory at a predetermined common address in both processes. But, there's much missing here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: yes, I think that's the only case when it makes sense; if so, it's solved simply by using a `uint32_t` in the 64-bit process (since the shared address *has* to fit into a 32 bit integer if it fits in the 32 bit address space) and then casting it to pointer when you need to use it. But I too think that we are missing a lot of context.

Comment: Thanks guys. I checked the codes. The two pointers actually are not used during the communicating. They are maintained separately at the individual app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must be aware that for the "other" process the pointer cannot be seen as pointer.

You can modify the pointer but not read data from the pointer or write data to it.

The idea to use "int32_t" of "Kerrek SB" would make sense in this case; however using "uint64_t" is more useful because this would allow the 32-bit process to modify a pointer pointing to an address space that is larger than 4 GiB:

```
typedef union {
    uint32_t *ptr;
    uint64_t address;
} maxaddr;
```

Instead of using "hb.old++" you would use "hb.old.address+=sizeof(uint32_t)".